# Graphs - How to count the minimum number of "broken roads" necessary to go from v1 to v2?

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

Given a graph (undirected, no-weighted and all vertices are connected to eachother), I need to find the minimum number of "bad edges" I must visit to go from A to B. For example, if there's a graph with 5 vertices and the bad edges are: (0,1), (0,2), (0,3) and (0,4), to go from 0 to 4 I'll need to visit at least 1 bad edge. It could be straightfoward from 0 to 4 or from 0 to 1 and then 1 to 4. The length of the path doesn't matter at all. I'm trying a modified BFS to do the job but I'm not quite sure if this is the right way. My modification is instead of using a queue, use a list and when I find a bad edge, I put it into the back of the list, so I'll only visit this edge if really necessary, but found out that it won't minimize the number of bad edges. Any advices?

Comment: This is a weighted shortest path problem, with the bad roads having a weight of 1 and the good roads a weight of 0.  From there, I would refer you to the wikipedia page:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem.

Comment: Seems interesting... Thanks for the comment. I'll try it and reply you soon! :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff While true, reducing to weighted shortest path is sub optimal in terms of asymptotical time complexity.

Comment: If you put the neighbors reachable by unbroken roads at the front of the queue and the neighbors reachable by broken roads at the back, then that should be a correct algorithm. That sounds like what you tried to do -- post some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it can indeed be solved by weighted shortest path, there is actually a more efficient (in terms of run time solutions).

First, define an auxillary graph `G'=(V,E')` where `e` is in `E'` iff `e` is "good". This step is linear in the size of the graph.

Now, you can find connected components in `G'` using DFS or BFS in `O(|V|+|E|)`.

Next, all you have to do is "collapse" all nodes to a single node that represent them (this is also linear time), and add the "bad edges" (note that there is never a "good edge" that connects between two components, or they would have been in the same component).

Now, you can run BFS on the new graph, and the length of the path is the minimal number of nodes needed.

While this is significantly more complex to implement than a simple weighted shortest path, this solution offers `O(|V|+|E|)` (which in your graph is `O(|E|)`) run time, compared to `O(|E|log|V|)` of weighted shortest path.

Comment: . . This is definitely a good solution, and probably more efficient than any general-purpose shortest path algorithm.